# Call client windows service from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, windows-services

I have an asp.net application that must call a client windows service that will start an exe previouslly installed in the client computer.
I use `ServiceController` class to manage the service: `sc = new ServiceController("HippoTwain", Environment.MachineName);`
I call the service using `sc.ExecuteCommand((int)HippoTwainMethods.Select);`
Then, the service does:

```
ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(@"C:\HippoCard\HTwain\HTwain.exe", out procInfo);
```

The problem is: The asp.net is calling the Server service, but I need to call the service from the Client computer.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the service installed on the client computer, you obviously have to call it from the client. That means either from a Silverlight control or from javascript.

What I suggest is to make the Windows service host a web service on localhost. Inside this web service add a method that once called starts your process.
On your page add a Silverlight control that calls the above method or make a jquery.post() call to that method. Obviously you need to mind the security issues, but you get the idea: you can't access a resource on the client-side using code executed server-side.